# fb comments href not working whith angularjs

Tags: facebook, angularjs, angularjs-scope, facebook-comments, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have installed below FB plugin on my page where I have specified data-href as below:

```
<div class="fb-comments"  data-href="http://pingle.com/ngdemo" data-width="550px" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

But when I am trying to set a scope value to it to make URL speicific it is not taking it and while checking on firefox, value {{ post.id }} is not getting added to the URL in fb DIV.

```
    <div class="fb-comments"  data-href="http://pingle.com/ngdemo?postId={{ post.id }}" data-width="550px" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

PS: when I print it on html, just above fb plugin, it displays nicely? is there a way to append scope value to data-href attribute of fb comment??

Answer (score 1):

Try `ng-attr-*` like this

```
<div class="fb-comments"  ng-attr-data-href="http://pingle.com/ngdemo?postId={{ post.id }}" data-width="550px" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Comment: I tried it as you said, i.e. in controller I added: $scope.commentURL = 'http://pingle.com/ngdemo?postId='+post.id; and in UI "<div class="fb-comments"  ng-attr-data-href="commentURL" data-width="550px"
                     data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>" But its not working. and I checked the firebox console and it seems its taking it as empty and taking current page URL by default

Comment: I hope, now it should work. Ref - http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_-attribute-bindings

Comment: If I am adding ng-attr to data-href of fb plugin, the plugin itself is not showing up!